# Do I have to use UNION insted of JOIN?

Tags: join, mysqli, union

An article about [Optimizing your SQL queries](http://hungred.com/useful-information/ways-optimize-sql-queries/) has suggested to use Union insted of OR `cause:

> Utilize Union instead of OR
>
> Indexes lose their speed advantage when using them in OR-situations in
> MySQL at least. Hence, this will not be useful although indexes is
> being applied 1   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_A = 'value' OR
> COLUMN_B = 'value'
>
> On the other hand, using Union such as this will utilize Indexes.
> 1- SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_A = 'value'
> 2- UNION
> 3- SELECT * FROM
> TABLE WHERE COLUMN_B = 'value'

How much this suggestion is true? Should I turn my OR queries to Union?

Comment: The astute reader will notice that those examples involve ORing conditions that operate on **different** columns, which is certainly not accidental. Are your own ORs like that?

Comment: Positive. What do you suggest?

Comment: Out of my field, so can't say. But you could `EXPLAIN` both queries and see what MySql thinks about them.

Comment: @Jon - drat.  Clearly I'm only the first half of astute this morning.  :-)

Comment: I assume of course that indexes exist on each individual column?  Otherwise it would not be more efficient whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend this as a general rule.  I don't have MySQL installed here so can't check the generated execution plan, but certainly in Oracle the plans are much different and the 'OR' plan is more efficient than the 'UNION' plan.  (Basically, the 'UNION' has to perform two SELECT's and then merge the results - the 'OR' only has to do a single SELECT).  Even a 'UNION ALL' plan has a higher cost than the 'OR' plan.  Stick with the 'OR'.

I very strongly recommend writing the clearest, simplest code you possibly can.  To me, that means you should use the 'OR' rather than the 'UNION'.  I've found over the years that attempting to "pre-optimize" something, or in other words to guess where I'll encounter performance problems and then to try and code around those problems, is a waste of time.  Code tends to spend a lot of time in the darndest places, and you'll only find them once you've got your code running.  A long time ago I learned three rules that I've found to be useful in this context:

1. Make if run.
2. Make it run right.
3. Make it run right fast.

Optimization is literally the last thing you should be doing.

Share and enjoy.

---

Followup:  I hadn't noticed that the 'OR' was looking at different columns (my bad), but my advice regarding "keep it simple" still holds.

Comment: If it were a matter of code clarity, I'd say you were right, but SQL queries deal with gigantic while loops that involve possibly millions of records.  If you don't optimize these, what do you optimize?

Comment: @Neil: in my experience optimization can only be attempted when there's a performance problem.  If and until there's a performance problem there's nothing to optimize, and as such optimization efforts will be wasted on things that aren't an issue.  I've found it best to write the cleanest and simplest code possible because A) most of the time it'll work just fine, and B) when and if a performance issue *does* arise the simple code can be understood easily so that a better performing version can be created.

Comment: @Bob_Jarvis: Difference of opinion then.  I think if optimizing doesn't mean sacrificing clarity, you should do it.  I don't think unions are unclear, rather the contrary.  Sometimes combining long sql queries into a single select can be quite difficult to read, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to think of indexes like names in a phone book.  A phone book, you could say, has a  naturally ordered index by name, meaning, if you want to find all names John Smith, it would take you little to no time to find it.  You'd simply open the phone book to the S section and begin looking up Smith.

Now what if I told you to look for entries in the phone book with name John Smith or phone number 863-2253.  Not as quick to do, eh?  To provide a precise answer, you'd need a phone book to look up John Smith and another one sorted by phone numbers in order to find a name by his or her phone number.

Perhaps a more sophisticated engine could see the need for this separation and do it automatically, but apparently MySQL does not.  So while it might seem a hassle to have to do it this way, I assure you the difference in tables with high record counts is noticeable.